# How can you get system generated alertview for address book

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on Address book in My application,I just want to get an `alertview` for accessing Address.How Can i show System Generated Alert for accessing `addressBook`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the user a custom message when asking for permission to use their contacts or address book, instead of the default one shown above, you need to add this field to your Info.plist file:

```
NSContactsUsageDescription
```

Here is apple developer link for the same:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW14

Comment: Is there any System Generated message to access Address book?actually I have added "NSContactUsageDescription" in Plist.But how Can I call That method in my Application

Comment: @DivakarReddy No there is no any method for the same but once you create Addressbook object for fetching contacts, it will asks for the permission.

Comment: I have added "NSContactsUsageDescription"  in Plist.But How can Call that method In my app.Which class reference Can i use to Call That Method.Suppose if we use MapKit.we need to Use "WhenInUseAuthorizationMethod"

Comment: After you created AB ...

ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
call the following ...

ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, nil);
This will display prompt for user to allow your application access "contacts"; As the second parameter you may get result callback and behave accordingly. Please refer to Apple documentation

Comment: [_contactStore requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error]

Comment: In My Application they use this method here they Have written logic under this method?

Comment: In My Application They have Used Both Contacts as well as Address Book.How Can i show user access permission for Contacts.Can you please write code for Accessing Permission from.It is very Urgent For me?

Comment: @ Bhadresh Mulsaniya In my Application They used both Contacts FrameWork as well as Address Book.I am not getting how to Show asking Permission.So far I have not worked on this domain.Can you please send Any Code or any idea regarding this.Very Urgent

Comment: Please refer this link : https://www.raywenderlich.com/63885/address-book-tutorial-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

```
// Check the authorization status of your application for Address Book
-(void)checkAddressBookAccess
{
    switch (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus())
    {
            // Update our UI if the user has granted access to their Contacts
        case  kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
            [self showAddressBook];
            break;
            // Prompt the user for access to Contacts if there is no definitive answer
        case  kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined :
            [self requestAddressBookAccess];
            break;
            // Display a message if the user has denied or restricted access to Contacts
        case  kABAuthorizationStatusDenied:
        case  kABAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning"
                                                            message:@"You have not granted access to your contacts or you have revoked it earlier."
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

// Prompt the user for access to their Address Book data
-(void)requestAddressBookAccess
{
    TF_Message_View_Controller * __weak weakSelf = self;

    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(self.addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error)
                                             {
                                                 if (granted)
                                                 {
                                                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                         [weakSelf showAddressBook];

                                                     });
                                                 }
                                             });
}
```

Comment: In My Application They have Used Both Contacts as well as Address Book.How Can i show user access permission for Contacts.Can you please write code for Accessing Permission from.It is very Urgent For me?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to show the alert asking for permission, you can use the following code

**This code works with Contacts framework, which is available only for iOS 9.0+**

```
- (void)checkContactStoreAccess {
    self.contactsStrore = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];

    switch ([CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts]) {
        case CNAuthorizationStatusAuthorized: {
            [self fetchContactsFromContactStore];
            break;
        }
        case CNAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:{
            [self requestContactsAccess];
            break;
        }
        case CNAuthorizationStatusDenied:
        case CNAuthorizationStatusRestricted:{
            //show info that access denied for contact and redirect user to settings with 
            [UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
        }
    }
}
- (void)requestContactsAccess {
    typeof(self)  __weak weakSelf = self;
    [self.contactsStrore requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        [weakSelf fetchContactsFromContactStore];
    }];
}
```

Comment: In My Application They have Used Both Contacts as well as Address Book.How Can i show user access permission for Contacts.Can you please write code for Accessing Permission from.It is very Urgent For me?

Comment: Do We have any Code Regarding about please send here.It would be more useful for me?

Comment: what should i write under  fetchContactsFromContactStore method